# Office 365 in English but changing default editing language

Tags: windows-8.1, microsoft-office, office365

I have a quite frustrating problem. I want to use Windows and Office 365 in default English language but use my local (Czech) language as editing one. My problem is that no matter how many times I choose Czech as default editing language in Word/PowerPoint and confirm it as soon as I restart or create a new document or slide in PP, english is back as the editing language.

How can this be solved?

PowerPoint probably does not like me since I disabled spell checker in options but it stills corrects my words. (It switches default languages to English and creates English words from my Czech ones)

I have Windows 8.1 and my keyboard is set as: English (United States) Czech keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Start a Office program, go to options -> language and add your desired editing language.

See screenshot:

[image: language options]